# C++ serialize multiple objects to one file and deserialize limited number of them

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, vector, boost-serialization

Before I start, consider this code:

One data transfer object ObjectDTO

```
class ObjectDTO {

public:
    int id;
    string string1;
    string string2;
    string string3;
    int code1;
    vector<string> stringList1;

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &archive, const unsigned int version) {
        archive & id;
        archive & string1;
        archive & string2;
        archive & string3;
        archive & code1;
        archive & stringList1;
    }
```

Serialization

```
void OutputStreamService::writeReportsToFile(vector<ObjectDTO> objects, int filename){
    ofstream outputFileStream(to_string(filename));
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive outputArchive(outputFileStream);
    outputArchive << objects;
}
```

Deserialization

```
vector<ObjectDTO> InputStreamService::readObjects() {
    ifstream inputFileStream(to_string(fileNumber++));
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive inputArchive(inputFileStream);
    vector<ObjectDTO> objects;
    inputArchive >> objects;
    return objects;
}
```

I am using Boost Serialization C++ librarys to serialize a `vector` of `ObjectDTO`s and read it back later.

Supose i generated 30GB of random `ObjectDTO`s and saved it to the same file

How can i read only some of them to avoid reaching memory limit?

I am using Boost Serialization because it was the simples way i found  to solve the first problem **but i can change to any other approach if necessary!**

Comment: You're apparently reading the file on a different system than where you generate it? Have you considered memory-mapping (Boost Interprocess `managed_mapped_file` comes to mind)?

Comment: @sehe that's not the case. The program displays three options: create and save(random generated data), search and delete. Each of them must be done with pagination provided by the user(save 1000 ObjectDTOs in 10 files, search 5 ObjectDTOs in a file with 1000). The main problem here is that i can't load the whole file to get this 5 ObjectDTOs i mentioned in the last example... because in some situations the file can be greater than memory you know? I will take a look at `managed_mapped_file` anyway!

Comment: How can you serialize it if is too  big to fit in memory. If you can serialize it you can on principle deserialise on the same machine

Comment: @sehe my bad, i misunderstood your first statement. Imagine i can run this program on another machine and then transfer it with the whole database generated in the first run. (That a really weird situation, but the whole point is on reading only some objects from the file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem discarding Boost Serialization and vectors in favor of arrays with plain old C++ `write` and `read` on `ofstream` and `ifstream` respectively.

My OutputStreamService writeObjectsToFile ended like this:

```
void OutputStreamService::writeObjectssToFile(ObjectDTO * objects, int filename){
        ofstream outputFileStream(to_string(filename), std::ios::binary);
        outputFileStream.write((char *)&objects, sizeof(objects));
}
```

And InputStreamService with readObjects:

```
ObjectDTO * InputStreamService::readObjects() {
    ifstream inputFileStream(to_string(fileNumber++), std::ios::binary);
    ObjectDTO objects[10];
    inputFileStream.read((char *)&objects, sizeof(objects));
    return objects;
}
```

This way i can define `10` or any other integer as the number of objects i want to read in.

To solve the mais problem, i can now calculate the aprox number of objects my memory can handle and then limit the number of reads!

Ty!

Comment: 1) Your `ObjectDTO` class is not a POD, this won't work. 2) Your code above is broken in several other ways.

Comment: @beerboy if you open your ofstream with ios::binary then you aren't limited to PODs.

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Protocol buffers instead, there are CodedOutputStream class for serialization and CodedInputStream for deserialization.

One of CodedOutputStream methods is WriteVarint32, which allows to write a number which could be used as an index in the stream.

In CodeInputStream there is corresponding ReadVarint32 method, eg.

Serialization:

```
char text[[]] = "Hello world!";
coded_output->WriteVarint32(strlen(text));
coded_output->WriteRaw(text, strlen(text));
```

Deserialization:

```
uint32 size;
coded_input->ReadVarint32(&size);

char* text = new char[size + 1];
coded_input->ReadRaw(buffer, size);
```

The last line allows you to read the content of serialized stream starting from given index.

Here are my two methods to serialize/deserialize streams with given length at the start.

```
template < class T>
void TProtoBufSerializer::SerializeImplementation(const T& protoBuf, std::vector<char>& buffer ) 
{
    int bufLength = protoBuf.ByteSize() + google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::VarintSize32(protoBuf.ByteSize());
    buffer.resize(bufLength);

    google::protobuf::io::ArrayOutputStream arrayOutput(&buffer[0], bufLength);
    google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream codedOutput(&arrayOutput);

    codedOutput.WriteVarint32(protoBuf.ByteSize());
    protoBuf.SerializeToCodedStream(&codedOutput);     
}

template < class T>
bool TProtoBufSerializer::DeSerializeImplementation(std::vector<char>& buffer, T& protoBuf )
{
   bool deserialized = false;

   google::protobuf::io::ArrayInputStream arrayInput(&buffer[0],buffer.size());
   google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream codedInput(&arrayInput);

   unsigned int object_size;
   bool header_readed = codedInput.ReadVarint32(&object_size);

   if(header_readed && object_size > 0)
   {
       if( buffer.size() >= codedInput.CurrentPosition() + object_size )
       {
           google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::Limit limit = codedInput.PushLimit(object_size);

           if(protoBuf.ParseFromCodedStream(&codedInput))
           {
               std::vector<char>::iterator it = buffer.begin();
               std::advance(it,codedInput.CurrentPosition());
               std::move(it,buffer.end(),buffer.begin() );
               buffer.resize(buffer.size() - codedInput.CurrentPosition());
               deserialized = true;
           }
           else
           {
              throw TProtoBufSerializerPayloadException();
           }
           codedInput.PopLimit(limit);
       }
   }
   else
   {
       //varint32 which is used in header is at the most 5 bytes long, 
       //if given buffer is 5 bytes or more long and header still cannot be decoded - raise exception 
       if(buffer.size() >= 5) 
       {
          throw TProtoBufSerializerHeaderException();
       }
   }
   return deserialized;
}
```

Comment: What is that `[[]]` and `[[]size+1]` syntax? Also, what exactly does this do that `std::fstream` doesn't?

Comment: sorry I copied and pasted it from here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.coded_stream#classes-in-this-file, fstream is dealing with file while this is about (de)serialization - putting the content of file into c++ objects

Comment: Hello @MarekWaszkiewicz, i ended up using one native approach but thanks for your answear and hope it can help other viewers!